# Preventing a div from becoming a yui-menu , when it is used inside a ul which is a yui-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yui

I am dynamically generating a layout thumbnail code for shindig, which will create a preview/thumbnail of the layout and place it inside a drop down menu.

The issue is, that if a div is put inside `<ul/>` or `<li/>` element , or for that matter any part of their hierarchy, it is converted to a yui-overlay or yui-menu itself.

Because of this, the layout previews are not appearing , and if by some way I do show them ,then click event for them is not being triggered.

Has anyone faced a similar issue before this? Or does someone has some insight into how can this be done??

Thanks,
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `span` with the style `display: block` instead. With this style, it behaves like a `div` but the overlay will probably leave it alone.

Comment: The overlay converts the span into a yui-label.So this didn't work.